# Lining up .asc XY points with DXF using QGIS 2.0

Tags: qgis, affine-transformation

I've exported XY points (nodes of a polyline with attributes) (.asc) from Star APIC and attempted to import it into QGIS as a delimited text file. I cannot however get it to line up correctly with the corresponding DXF file I exported from the same database. My DXF lines up with aerial photographs, so I am sure it is correctly projected. The CSV should be in the same projection (since it comes from the same database). I am considering using the Affine Transformation plugin to rescale and transform. Is this the best solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out APIC .asc exports its XY coordinates in centimeters. All I had to do was divide by 100 to get to meters again. This is why the CSV points didn't line up with the DXF (all coordinates were inflated, thus making the scale and location incorrect). Now that coordinates are in correct units, the two files line up in QGIS as expected.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: i ended up finding my own solution/mistake. I believe this is the answer to my question, as I fixed the problem as described.

Comment: Believe it or not, you ended up applying an affine transformation (scaling both axes) :)